# Структура проекта java

Tags: java, project

Начинаю программировать на java. Столкнулся с недопонимание. 
В java проектом будет выступать папка, которая содержит в себе папку src, то есть, если есть

*data/myproject/src/com/...*,

то проектом будет myproject, но он просто вложен в папку data.

Тогда вопросы:

1. Если мне нужно создать несколько проектов, то есть несколько папок, содержащих в себе папки src, например:

*myprojects/mypr1/src/com...*
*myprojects/mypr2/src/com...*
*myprojects/mypr3/src/com...*

Будет ли при этом папка myprojects считаться проектом или это просто три проекта, вложенных в одну папку.

(Троеточие это я просто путь не продолжаю писать, названия путей выдуманы тоже для примера, не судите строго)

2. Самое главное. Допустим, мне нужно создать в проекте, помимо самой папки с исходниками, папку с картинками. Можно ли вкладывать данную папку прямо в корень проекта, где находится папка src(1), или стоит создать для них отдельные папки(2)?

(1)

*mypro/src/com/...*

*mypro/images/...*

(2)

*mypro/project/src/com/...*

*mypro/images/...*

Comment: если например смотреть на maven, то там определена структура проекта: src/main/java - для исходников, src/main/resources - для ресурсов

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от `проекта` и `фреймворков`. Да, в самых простеньких проектах типа `Swing` или `FX` это не критично. Можно оставить и 3 проекта в одной папке, но при этом с разным содержанием `src`, проблем не будет. Но когда приложения будут строиться на `Spring Boot` с использованием `gradle`/`maven` могут вылезти ошибки, так как `archetype` разный у всех, и в частности на Ваш выбор. Отвечая на Ваш вопрос можно сказать, да - будут 3 разных проекта(но вопрос в том, не будут ли они друг-другу мешать).